# Jquery Overlay not displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I want to show an overlay when my visitors leaving the website with the courser, here is a working [demo](http://goo.gl/eHbtvj)

But when I include it to my real site, it is not displayed [real site](http://goo.gl/E3VfyQ)

The page just turns grey, but the modal is not displayed.

Here is the cource code of the overlay: https://github.com/carlsednaoui/ouibounce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this following code when your popup load

You need to add this line in ouibounce.js in below mentioned function

```
  function fire() {

   $("#ouibounce-modal .modal").show();
   if (isDisabled()) { return; }

   if (el) { el.style.display = 'block'; }


   callback();

   disable();

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I added it but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using "ouibounce.js" or "ouibounce.min.js"?

Comment: I have download source as per given link and try to implement that same scenario. So I have observed that when popup open then "fire()" function call.

Comment: Else you can try with  $(".modal").show(); also. Please try this one in same place.

Comment: I edited the wrong file, it works now. Thank you so much for that.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `display: none` from your modal and it should work.

Your modal stays hidden at all times regardless of `z-index`.